# Sample player that shows ffmpeg libstagefright.cpp usage

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am trying to write ffmpeg and OMXIL based mediaplayer.Facing issues in compiling the code with so many header files and libraries to include for android media framework.
Is there any sample player that uses ffmpeg libstagefright.cpp so that i can understand its usage and base my player on that.

Regards
Mayank